# Keysight bandwidth and rise time

Tags: filter, measurement, bandwidth

According to the [following application note](https://edadocs.software.keysight.com/kkbopen/how-can-you-avoid-selecting-an-oscilloscope-probe-with-the-wrong-bandwidth-587208673.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20fix%20this%20pitfall,1.5%20GHz%20or%20more%20bandwidth.) from Keysight, one way to know what device to take for measuring a signal is to measure the rise time. Then according to the rise time of the system under studies, the bandwidth of the measurement device can be known. The formula is the following :

[image]

The 0.35 is only true for a first order transfer function Vout/Vin. Nevertheless, if I took, for example, a differential probe, the transfer function does not look like a first order transfer function:

[image]

Is the formula given by Keysight really reaslistic?

Comment: You cannot precisely characterize the entire transfer function of a system with a single number, so rise time is necessarily an approximation.  Usually it is good enough, but if not, measure the entire impulse response to get the exact transfer function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a rough rule of thumb, not a precise metrology-grade calculation.

The app note you referred to suggests using it to estimate the bandwidth of your signals, and suggests other methods for determining the bandwidth of your probe, such as using a VNA, using a swept sine-wave source, and using a step-response measurement and FFT.

Of course the step response method will require using a step source with a substantially higher bandwidth (or shorter rise time) than the probe you are trying to measure. The differentiation process also tends to enhance high-frequency noise so you may want to use trace averaging in the scope before capturing the data for analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)  Well my question was probably not clear I do not want to characterize a probe. I want to know what probes to take for measuring correctly the signal. Suppose I have a signal whose the rise time is known. What probes I have to take ? Can I make a link between the rise time and the derivative of a sinewave at 0 at a particular frequency ?

Comment: You should use a probe with bandwidth substantially higher than \$0.35 / t_R\$. 10x higher if possible. Then it doesn't matter if the 0.35x rule of thumb is precisely correct or not.